# PHP webshop shopping cart real-time subtotal

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, shopping-cart

I have a webshop like `cart` system you can add items to the cart and they will appear there. I store the product's quantity and the price. I also have a `+` and `-` buttons so you can change the stored quantity by 1. Only one function missing: When the user clicks on for instance the `+` button, it incrises the quantity and stores it in the datebase immediately. BUT sadly it won't show the new price (multiply the original price with the new quantity value). If I reload the page, the price will be multiplied, but I can't figue out how to show the new price right after I click onto the `+` button. I need some idea how you would do this?

`index.php`

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHEN 1";
$res = $con-> query($sql);
if ($res -> num_rows > 0) { $subtot = 0; // Subtotal variable to save the new subtotal
   while ($item = $res-> fetch_assoc()) {
      echo ''; // Display the items with their data using HTML
      // I also have the JS script here, so I can use the `+` and `-` button functions
      // I use ajax, and pass the product's id and the new quantity to a new .php file (for example up.php)
     // Add the values to the subtot varialbe
     $subtot += $item['price'] * $item['quantity']; // So on page refresh I get the item's price and value so I can multiply the price and show the subtotal.
     // I think somewhere here should be the code to update the `$subtotal` on the `+` button click to multiply the price with the new quantity, but I can't change php variables on js button clicks.
   }
}
echo $subtotal; // Display the subtotal
```

The `+` button script:

```html
document.getElementById("plusbutton").addEventListener("click", () => { if var bsi__data = new FormData(); bsi__data.append("pid", "'.$product['pid'].'"); bsi__data.append("quantity", document.getElementById("bspq__inp'.$product['pid'].'").value); bsi__data.append("price", "'.$product['product_price'].'");
$.ajax({
enctype: "multipart/form-data", type: "POST", url: "/assets/php/basket/q__up.php", data: bsi__data, dataType: "json", contentType: false, processData: false,
success: function(data) { console.log(data); su__refresh(); },
error: function (data) { console.log("error"); console.log(data); }
});
});
```

And finally the `up.php`

```js
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE cart SET quantity = ? WHERE pid = ? AND uid = ?')) {
            $stmt->bind_param('iii', $_POST['quantity'], $_POST['pid'], $uid);$stmt->execute(); die('ok');
        } else { die ("error");
```

Comment: You need to share the HTML snippet as well.